# Restart the computer when the system freeze

Tags: macos

I'm working on a code but sometimes the memory gets full and the system freeze. I've been searching a little bit and there is an option that restarts the computer when the system freeze, but I can't find that option in my iMac. It's important to mention that the Mac is in another place. I access to the Mac through AnyDesk but as I mentioned some times the Mac freeze and I can't be in that place to reboot it manually, I want to know if there is an automatically way to reboot when the computer freeze. I'm using macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: Have you tried holding down the power button until the system reboots?  If the OS has stopped responding to the mouse or keyboard, this will restart the system.

Comment: I know but the computer is in another place, sometimes it freezes when I'm not in that place.

Comment: That would be good info to include in the original question.  You won't get helpful answers if leave critical info out of the question.  Please [edit] the question to add that.

Comment: If you are accessing your computer through ssh (terminal), then ```reboot``` command would work in the terminal.

Comment: @fsb thanks. I add extra information to the question

Comment: @AnshulChoudhary thanks to answer. Right now I'm using AnyDesk because I'm having problems connecting my computer through ssh.

Comment: I would keep a terminal open so that you can run a kill comnmand to kill the app under development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

`sudo systemsetup -setrestartfreeze on`

just need to setup this once. It keeps the setting forever, until someday you set it to `off` again.

Comment: You are welcome.